# How to access data of a particular record in python dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

```
marksList = [['name', ['Anand', 'Bhanu', 'Chetna', 'Durga', 'Eshwar']],
         ['english', [65,83,47,57,78]],
         ['hindi', [78,64,84,59,65]],
         ['maths', [85,74,74,95,84]],
         ['science', [58,94,59,78,68]],
         ['social', [72,65,82,49,65]]]
          
marksDict = dict(marksList)
marksDict['maths'][0]
```

How Can I access Anand's marks in Mathematics? Can I use the above code or is there any other way using for loop?

Comment: You would have to know that "Anand" is element #0 (which you can find out using `marksDict['name'].index('Anand')`) and then `marksDict['maths'][0]`.  If you have 2D data like this with named columns, you might consider pandas instead.

Comment: Do you have control over how the data is originally structured? There are better ways.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have "records". Dictionaries are *maps* from keys to values*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the list to a nicer format:

```
marksDict = {}
for i,name in enumerate(marksList[0][1]):
    marksDict[name] = {}
    for subject in marksList[1:]:
        marksDict[name][subject[0]] = subject[1][i]
```

Output:

```
{
'Anand': {'english': 65, 'hindi': 78, 'maths': 85, 'science': 58, 'social': 72},
'Bhanu': {'english': 83, 'hindi': 64, 'maths': 74, 'science': 94, 'social': 65},
'Chetna': {'english': 47, 'hindi': 84, 'maths': 74, 'science': 59, 'social': 82},
'Durga': {'english': 57, 'hindi': 59, 'maths': 95, 'science': 78, 'social': 49},
'Eshwar': {'english': 78, 'hindi': 65, 'maths': 84, 'science': 68, 'social': 65}
}
```

Then you can access with:

```
marksDict['Anand']['maths']
```